# Operating on objects using Flash AS3 that were created manually by a designer in the timeline

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I was trying to build an application where a designer has created content on the timeline as a sequence of key frames.  Each key frame is completely different.  When the application is started I choose one of the frames, move the play head to that frame and stop (using gotoAndStop).  Next, by referring to symbols in the key frame by name, I use AS3 to allow drag and drop, and I also do some programmatic movement.

The problem is that when I move to a different key frame on the timeline using gotoAndStop, the symbols that were touched by AS3 in the previous frame, even if they are not referenced by the designer's key frame, show up on the stage.  It is as though any DisplayObject that I touch with AS3 becomes divorced from the timeline.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to programatically work with timeline (MovieClip) content that was manually created by a designer.  This just seems like it should be a really common use case.  It seems that about the only thing I can do safely with the timeline is to move the play head and respond to events (if I don't change the state of DisplayObjects in the timeline).  Also, is there any good documentation on how objects get allocated and destroyed when the timeline plays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when I move to a different key frame on the timeline using gotoAndStop, the symbols that were touched by AS3 in the previous frame, even if they are not referenced by the designer's key frame, show up on the stage. It is as though any DisplayObject that I touch with AS3 becomes divorced from the timeline.

**If you are not adding and removing things from the display object list, or toggling object depth, that should not be the case at all.**

Are you sure they are not being referenced by the designers keyframe at all? Otherwise you might want to try a different approach than just coding in the timeline.

One way to merge FLAs with custom code is to have the movie clip symbols created by the designer, have them exported extending a custom AS class. This way the designer can fiddle with the look and your .as class can control functionality.

To do this, set your movieclip to "Export for ActionScript" and then choose a class file that you wrote in the "Class" field. Make sure your class extends `MovieClip`.

This is also awesome because you can code in your AS file as the designer is working in Flash and you dont have to share the same file.

*This doesn't necessarily solve all your problems, rather it is a workflow recommendation that might work for you*

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I don't add or remove anything from the display list, however, at the beginning of a DisplayObject drag I do call setChildIndex on the parent of the dragged object to move it to the top of the z order list.  Is this what you are referring to by "toggling object depth"?

Comment: Yeah, that will mess with the display object list, even though you aren't doing it explicitly. So that's your problem. Maybe try removing it from the keyframes where you don't want it to persist, if you don't want to go with a more robust solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to adjust the z-order for the drag to make sure the dragged Sprite is on top.  Is there any way to do that without breaking the timeline?

Comment: Nope. Timeline animation has its limits. If you are going to change the x-index explicitly with AS, then you will need to explicitly hide it from the other frames where you don't want it, with AS.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help!  I removed the SetChildIndex and it fixed all of the strange behavior.  I will talk to the designer to make sure everything draggable is at or close to the top.

Comment: Remember you can always upvote on top of marking the answer correct, which gives more rep to the person who provided the answer or maybe not even the right answer, just an answer with good information. :)

Comment: An indirect depth change doesn't cause the issue.  If your keyframed object starts at depth 0, and you insert a new object at depth 0 via ActionScript, the keyframing remains intact.  So it seems that something in setChildIndex is explicitly deactivating the keyframing, since an (indirect) depth-change alone isn't enough to trigger the unexpected behavior.